# Absolute link to PDF - Executable File?

Tags: .net, email, pdf

We have a mass emailing tool (.net based) that we developed in house.  html editor. and sends via html and text formats.

within the body we have an absolute URL path to a PDF on our server.  some of our subscribers are stating that when they click on the link they get a message box that the file is an executable file and whether they should run it or not...

why would that happen... and only to a certain group?

Comment: Can you post what the HTML source for the link looks like?

Comment: <a href="//www.example.com/providers/Communications/provider_updates/ChangeProviderNotification031510.pdf"
    target="_self">Provider Alert/Changes to Provider Phone Notification</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your problem, you need to indicate MIME type of content. In this case: **application/pdf**

Comment: In a php file, paste this code:
//begin
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
readfile('your_doc.pdf');
//end

Thus, browser is forced to display .pdf content, and will not suggest to download file.

Answer (score 0):

What did they open the email with, a browser (which? version?), or an email client?

I'm thinking that the issue could easily boil down to some IE settings.

Answer (score 0):

Is your path a local path? Like:

```
\\Server\pdf\example.pdf
```

Maybe this is triggering the executable warning?

Comment: No, it is an absolute URL path to our sever.